# DataFrame Value Can't Changed Using df.at

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

** DataFrame Value Can't Changed Using df.at**

DataFrame :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ['sani','akshay','jay'],
                  "B" : ['nan',1,'nan']})
```

Code:

```
d1 = {
    "sani" : [100] ,
    "himanshu" : [4],
    "jay" : [45]
}
```

```
for i,row in df.iterrows() :
    if row['B'] == 'nan':
        key = row['A']
        df.at[i,'B'] = d1[key]
```

Output:

```
          A       B
0       sani     nan
1      akshay     1
2        jay     nan
```

Excepted Output:

```
          A       B
0       sani     [100]
1      akshay     1
2        jay     [45]
```

**Additional context**

Can't Copy If Dictionary Keys Value are List Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first replace string `'nan'` with `NaN`, and then use `map` with `fillna()` as follows:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map(d1).replace('nan',np.nan).fillna(df['B'])
```

prints:

```
        A      B
0    sani  [100]
1  akshay      1
2     jay   [45]
```

Comment: nan is not np.nan is a string